# Any Specific Reason for not having Raam Lala in Mandir at Home

Tags: rama, temple

Most of the Hindus, in there Mandir at home have Laddu Gopal, but very few (in fact I have seen none) who have Raam Lala (Bal Raam), is there any specific reason for such behavior? Are Hindus allowed to have Baal Rama in their Mandir at Home as well?